# Why is pair of const trivially copyable but pair is not?

Tags: c++

```
std::cout << std::boolalpha;
std::cout << std::is_trivially_copyable< std::pair<const int,int> >::value;
std::cout << std::is_trivially_copyable< std::pair<int,int> >::value;
```

When I use GCC 9.2 the output is `true` `false`.

When I use Clang 5.0 or GCC 5.2 the output is `false` `false`.

Why the difference?

Comment: For the record, the latest Clang also gives `true` `false`. MSVC gives `false` `false`.

Comment: With the remaining `const` combinations added: https://godbolt.org/z/VdYfcN (only `int, int` gives `false` in latest `clang` or `gcc`).

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/AgV7Gg it looks like it changed from gcc 6.2 to 6.3, so it seems like a bug maybe. I couldn't tell you though why const int is and int is not.

Comment: trying clang 5.0 from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable do different result from clang 5.0 on @MaxLanghof godbolt.

Comment: Is possible that the problem is about std lib implementation?

Answer (score 9):

`std::pair` has a non-trivial copy-assignment and move-assignment operator. This prevents it from being trivially copyable.

Since C++17, if one of the two contained types is not assignable, then the copy/move assignment operator is defined as deleted, which lifts this restriction on being trivially copyable. This is the case here because `const int` is not copy-assignable or move-assignable.

C++17 also states that if the two types have trivial destructors, then the pair will also have a trivial destructor, which is another requirement for being trivially copyable.

The older compilers you tested probably do not have full support for C++17, which prevents the pair from being trivially copyable even for `pair<const int, int>`.

Comment: I wonder why assignment operators are not `=default`ed, unlike copy/move constructors.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat That's a good question, I can't think of a reason.

Comment: Unfortunately, that still doesn't make pair required to be trivially move/copy assignable when both types are trivially move/copy assignable.  The standard would have to explicitly say that.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case the copy assignment operator and the move assignment operator are deleted. So the class is trivially-copyable.

In the second case at least the copy assignment operator is not deleted and is not trivial.

From the C++ 20 (11.1 Properties of classes)

> 1 A trivially copyable class is a class:
>
> (1.1) — where each copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment
>   operator, and move assignment operator (11.3.4.2,11.3.5) **is either
>   deleted or trivial**,
>   ...

Comment: You did not address at all the fact that the output differs between implementations, which I believe is the core point of the question.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I pointed out what are the current valid results of the expressions relative to the used objects.

Comment: And that's great but the question is "why that difference?" not "what are the current valid results"

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It means that other compilers do not satisfy the current C++ Standard.:)